# simple t.test vs lm

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, t-test, lm

I have a dataset with only two variables. y is a numeric variable, while x is a categorical variable with two categories A and B. When I run lm(y ~ x) I get t-value for coefficient to be 2.372. However, when I run simple t.test as t.test(y~x,data=df,var.equal=T) I get t-value to be -2.372.

Why is this? Any explanation if this relationship is true?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It has to do with how R is coding X. The two results are completely equivalent.  One is saying that A is higher than B while the other says B is lower than A.